# Sequelize Or in findAll();

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table in my database in which someone creates an entry with 3 different languages.  every language is stored in a separate column (Language1, Language2, Language3).  I need to search this table using 1 variable and return the rows where any of the 3 colums is equal to this variable.
the below code only search in 1 column (packageLanguage) but there are still packageLanguage2 and packageLanguage3 columns ... how do I do it?

```
var matchedPackagesId= packages.findAll({where: {packageLanguage: variable}});
```

Comment: Welcome @Ahmed, please can you format your code in the question so it is easier for users to follow. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: i edited the question so the code is showing now

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can try `or`ing

```
packages.findAll({
        where: {
            [Sequelize.Op.or] : [
                {
                    language1: {{YOUR_VARIABLE}}
                },
                {
                    language2: {{YOUR_VARIABLE}}
                },
                {
                    language3: {{YOUR_VARIABLE}}
                }
            ]
        }
    })
```